# PHP thread - run method not being called

Tags: php, pthreads

For some reason my run method is not being called? Any ideas where i'm going wrong?

```
<?php

    class WorkerThread extends Thread
    {
        private $i = 0;

        public function __construct( $i )
        {
            $this->i = $i;
        }

        public function run()
        {
            $a = 0;
            while( $a < 100 )
            {
                file_put_contents( "test" . $this->i . ".txt", $a, FILE_APPEND );
                                    sleep( 5 );
            }
        }

    }

    $workers = array();

    for ( $i = 0; $i < 3; $i++ )
    {
        $workers[ $i ] = new WorkerThread( $i );
        $workers[ $i ]->start();
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the while loop, `$a` never changes and causes an infinite loop (it's always equal to zero).

Comment: Thanks man, can't believe xdebug wasn't allowing me to see that!